# connecting SVN through maven

Tags: maven

I need to connect SVN through Maven. Below is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org  /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
      http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
       <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
       <groupId>com.sample.webapp</groupId>
       <artifactId>HellojBossApp</artifactId>
       <packaging>war</packaging>
       <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
       <name>HellojBossApp Maven Webapp</name>
       <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

       <scm>
         <connection>scm:svn:http://svn/PRONTO/trunk/dev</connection>
         <developerConnection>scm:svn:http://svn/PRONTO/trunk/dev</developerConnection>
         <url>http://svn/PRONTO/trunk/dev</url> 
       </scm>  
       <dependencies>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>  
        <build>
       <finalName>HellojBossApp</finalName>
         <plugins>
              <plugin>
             <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
             <artifactId>maven-scm-plugin</artifactId>
             <version>1.8.1</version>
             <configuration>
              <connectionType>connection</connectionType>
               <username>keerthana</username>
          <password>keerthana</password>
           <checkoutDirectory>${project.basedir}/co/src</checkoutDirectory>
          <workingDirectory>${project.basedir}/co/src</workingDirectory>
        </configuration>
            </plugin>
          </plugins>      
         </build>
      </project>
```

If i run using mvn:install the build is success. But i am not sure whether its connecting to SVN or not. How to check whether its connected to SVN?? Please help me.

I tried giving the goal as svn:checkout clean install but i get the following error

```
      [ERROR] The svn command failed.
      [ERROR] Command output:
      [ERROR] 'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
       operable program or batch file.

      Skipping HellojBossApp Maven Webapp
      [INFO] This project has been banned from the build due to previous failures.
      [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
      [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
      [INFO] Total time: 3.094s
      [INFO] Finished at: Wed Jun 26 11:14:05 IST 2013
      [INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
      [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

      [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.8.1:checkout (default-cli) on project HellojBossApp: Command failed.The svn command failed. -> [Help 1]
```

org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-scm-plugin:1.8.1:checkout (default-cli) on project HellojBossApp: Command failed.The svn command failed.

Please anyone help me to run the script and see the message that its connected to SVN.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SVN is not working in your case.

The log message

```
'svn' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

means that SVN is not installed on your system. You need to install SVN client first.

After that Maven will be able to check out the project.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working now. But i am not able to find anything in my checkout directory. The checkout folder is empty. Please help me in this.

Comment: Sorry i gave the goal wrongly so it was not checkout out.Now it's checked out properly. Thanks a lot for helping me.

Comment: Can u please tell me how to create the same project using command prompt? I tried by giving "mvn:archetype:generate". Its asking for some archetype number. I gave 15. And src and pom folder was created. But if i use the above pom.xml the build is failure. Please help me in this. Thanks

Comment: I have done the above task in command prompt. Now another doubt is How can i deploy the generated war file to my Jboss Server? Please help me in this.